# Android MediaPlayer - listeners - dismissDialog help

Tags: android, media

I am streaming live video.  When someone clicks "stream" a progress dialog appears which says, "Loading Video".  My problem is I have no way of knowing when to dismiss the dialog.  I would think that it should be dismissed when it starts buffering....but sometimes its buffering for 10 seconds before anything shows on the screen.  Is there a way of getting a notification when the video actually shows on the screen? (I can't find one).  How do I get my desired result? (And of course with live video, the buffering percent is always 0, so I can't dismiss on 100 percent or anything).  My code is basically identical to the Android MediaPlayer demo.  Here are my log outputs:

```
 onPrepared called
 onBufferingUpdate percent
 URL  rtsp://174.100.217.64:1935/live/Camera_00-12-AB-18-53-7A/YFtvtTwqdEO1_JbiXHs9ow.sdp               
 onVideoSizeChanged called
 onPrepared called
 startVideoPlayback
 onBufferingUpdate percent
 surfaceChanged called
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 onBufferingUpdate percent 0
 **VIDEO IS ACTUALLY SHOWN HERE**
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register an `OnPreparedListener` in your `VideoView` using the `setOnPreparedListener` method. These callback will be invoked when the media is loaded and ready to be played.

Comment: I am listening for that already. It gets called right before the first onBufferingUpdate gets called, which means I still have 10 seconds of nothing on the screen until video appears.  onPreparedListener is where I start my media player.

Comment: Please post some code. I'm currently streaming audio and video and the OnPreparedListener is working as expected.

Comment: I posted my output code.  So after it buffers for about 10 seconds then it shows video.  There are no other callbacks at that point except the continuall onBufferingUpdate